# wkhtmltopdf 'Access Denied' at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Tags: c#, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, access-denied

Used wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf it works fine but sometimes throws

> 'Access Denied' at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo)

For ex : in one go it generates 20 files out of which for one pdf  it throws 'Access denied'  and remianing 19 are generated fine. And most of the time all pdfs are generated fine. What to do in this case.

```
 public byte[] WKHtmlToPdf(string url)
    {
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid());
        //var wkhtmlDir = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\";
        //var wkhtml = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        var wkhtmlDir = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/wkhtmltopdf");
        var wkhtml = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe");
        var p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtml;
         p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlDir;

        string switches = "";
        switches += "--print-media-type ";
        switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
        switches += "--page-size Letter ";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = switches + " " + url + " " + fileName;
        p.Start();
    
       // wait or exit
        p.WaitForExit(60000);

        // read the exit code, close process
        int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();
        var outputFile = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory, fileName);
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(outputFile);

        return returnCode == 0 ? bytes: null;
    }
```

Comment: Is it the first 19 that work and the last 1 that fails or is it random?

Comment: Its random and when i run it again it works fine